# Installing nmap and keeping it undetectable

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, administrator, nmap, netcat

I have a administrative computer fully equipped with antivirus (avg,norton,malbytes. etc) that I want to install ncat(nmap) on and keep it as close to undetectable as possible. How would I do this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to keep it "undetectable"?

Comment: I recommend you to ask that as an another question at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, as you might find better answers there. This can stay here tho. Also nothing can be exactly undetectable. My "monitoring application" (to keep people off my pc) shows up in task manager's detailed list as gooff.exe, even though it is a SYSTEM process, I can cause a BSOD, but I can't remove it from that list.

Comment: Please define what you expect by "undetectable", and edit your question to include what you've attempted already, as well as the results.  This will show us that you've done some research, and stop people form offering answers you've already tried.

Comment: undetectable in the sense that if someone wasn't looking for it; they wouldn't find it. also so all the antiviruses aren't going off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netcat opens a hole in your network stack, if someone scans your computer they're going to find that hole. You could use a high port number around 60,000 where there is (very slightly) less chance of being detected. (if they only scan for popular ports)